# Build file format not correct, attepting to integrate scalariform autoformatter

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm attempting to implement scalariform autoformatter for Scala.

Here is build.sbt :

```
  import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._

import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

name := "MyApp"

scalariformSettings

ScalariformKeys.preferences := ScalariformKeys.preferences.value
  .setPreference(RewriteArrowSymbols, true)
  .setPreference(AlignParameters, true)
  .setPreference(AlignSingleLineCaseStatements, true)
  .setPreference(PlaceScaladocAsterisksBeneathSecondAsterisk, true)
  .setPreference(MultilineScaladocCommentsStartOnFirstLine, true)
```

plugins.sbt :

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0")
```

but when I perform `sbt reload` command receive error :

```
 error: object typesafe is not a member of package com
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._
```

Is build file format correct ?

Update : This appears to be a proxy issue : SBT does not seem to use my proxy settings.

Comment: Why are you trying to add an sbt plugin in `build.sbt` ? Shouldn't that go in `plugins.sbt` ?

Comment: @m-z yes, sorry. question updated

Comment: Read the [manual](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform)—no `import com.typesafe...` there. I guess you were looking at a fork or older version?